# How to execute sudo command with filter in elisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I would like to use elisp to execute a privileged command, then use a filter to do further processing when certain output is seen.

It's my understanding, after exhaustive RTFM'ing, that I can:

1. Set `default-directory` to a path that begins with "/sudo::/".
2. Call `start-file-process` to start a process that will be run under sudo.

Here is a function I wrote that tries to do this:

```lisp
(defun start-vpn (config-file password-file callback)
  "Starts the VPN connection, waits for a DHCP address,
then invokes callback with the address it got."
  (let* ((default-directory "/sudo::/tmp")
         (buff (get-buffer-create "*openvpn*"))
         (proc (start-file-process "openvpn" "*openvpn*"
                                   "/usr/local/sbin/openvpn"
                                   (concat "--config " config-file)
                                   (concat "--auth-user-pass " password-file))))
    (set-process-filter proc
                        (lambda (proc output)
                          (message "Got output: " output)
                          (let ((ip (get-vpn-ip-address output)))
                            (when ip
                              (callback ip)))))))
```

When I run this, I see the following output in the `*Messages*` buffer:

```
start-vpn
Tramp: Opening connection for root@localhost using sudo...
Tramp: Sending command `exec sudo -u root -s -H -p Password:'

Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell
Tramp: Sending command `exec sudo -u root -s -H -p Password:'
Tramp: Found remote shell prompt on `localhost'
Tramp: Opening connection for root@localhost using sudo...done
(lambda (proc output) (message "Got output: " output) (let ((ip ...)) (if ip (progn ...))))
Got output:
```

...and no output in the `*openvpn*` buffer the function creates.

I am not an expert at elisp, so I suspect there is some stupid mistake I am making. I am also really curious about the `"(lambda (proc ..."` in the `*Messages*` buffer.

Any advice, criticism, or tips appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the reason for seeing `(lambda ...` in the message buffer is that `set-process-filter` returns the filter function, so therefore `start-vpn` does too.

Your `message` call needs to contain a format specifier to actually show the output:

```
(message "Got output: %s" output)
```

And `(callback ip)` won't work for two reasons:

- Emacs Lisp has separate namespaces for functions and variables, so `(callback ip)` will call the *function* `callback` (which doesn't exist), while you need `(funcall callback ip)` to call the function stored in the *variable* `callback`.
- Once you're past that, since Emacs Lisp uses dynamic scope by default, by the time your lambda function gets called the binding for `callback` is already gone.

  In Emacs 24, you can set `lexical-binding` to `t`, and the code above should work.  In any case, you can explicitly use the `lexical-let` macro:

  ```
  (lexical-let ((callback callback))
    (lambda (proc output)
      (message "Got output: " output)
      (let ((ip (get-vpn-ip-address output)))
        (when ip
          (funcall callback ip))))
  ```

  This macro uses black magic to preserve the value of `callback` inside the lambda function.